# Angular 4 FlexBox IE10

Tags: angular, flexbox

I have the following html div code that works on Chrome, FireFox and MS Edge but on IE10 the output is stacked on top of each other.  Basically three flexbox column div in ascending order.

On the working browsers they are layout one after the other which is what I want.  Is the a way to fix the IE10 issue?  Thank you.

```
<div class="container">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"   style="text-align:center" >
    <div fxFlex="grow" fxFlexAlign="center" *ngIf="QrCode && !QrCompleted">
     {{DisplayCode}}
    </div>
    <div fxFlex fxFlexAlign="center" *ngIf="loginCode && !loginCompleted">
      <p>Display Count: {{cnt}} </p>
      <h1>Get Login Code from SMS to Login</h1>
      <p>  {{errorMessage}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"  *ngIf="LoginCompleted">
    <div  fxFlex="grow" >
          <button style="height:50px; width:200px" (click)="onClick()">Click for New Code</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"  >
  <div fxFlex="grow" >
    <a href="https://www.example.com/store" target="_blank">
          <img src="../assets/companylogo.svg" alt="Logo" height="100px" width="400px" >
    </a>
  </div>    
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexibility. It is a polyfill for flexbox to work on older browsers as well:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexibility

Comment: Yes it will. There is no reason it won't

Comment: I am not an expert but I think it will conflict with the flexbox (https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) that I am using now.